# Can't get upper axis values through linking with lower axis in gnu plot

Tags: formatting, gnuplot

I am trying to link the upper axis with the lower axis in gnu plot, that is print out values on the upper axis given a relationship between the upper axis quantities and the lower axis ones. The relationship between them is

`x2 = 2*c**2/(2*x1**2-c**2)` with `c=1.548458`.
The following should be sufficient

```
set xlabel "Quantity lower"
set xtics nomirror
set x2label "Quantity Upper"
set x2tics nomirror
set link x2 via 2*(2*1.548458)**2/(2*x**2-(2*1.548458)**2) inverse sqrt((2*1.548458)**2*(2+x)/2/x)

#set link x via 1239.8/x inverse 1239.8/x

set ylabel "Quantity y"
set ytics 0.2
set samples 400
Spectrum(x) = exp(-(x-500)**2/(400))

set xrange[30:2000]

set format x2 "%.2f"
plot Spectrum(x) w l title "Spectrum"
```

I've also log formatted the x axis via

`set logscale x
set format x "10^{%L}"`

but regardless of whether I include the log formatting I am unable to get any meanginful values printed out on the upper axis. (The function for y is for illustrative purposes only, the value for y in my actual script relies on reading in data from a file)

I'd like to print out values on the upper axis for say two values of x=100, 1000 say.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to set tics automatically. But at least you can set them explicitly.

You want to set x2 tics at given x1 values. As the `set x2tics` command takes tic positions in x2 coordinates, you    can convert the given x1 values into x2 values. I have modified your script to illustrate what I mean:

```
set xlabel "Quantity lower"
set xtics nomirror
set x2label "Quantity Upper"
set x2tics nomirror

# avoid warnings by setting the xrange before linking the axes
set xrange[30:2000]

# setup the link functions
c = 1.548458 # or 2*1.548458 ? 
link_x1_x2(x) = 2*c**2/(2*x**2-c**2) 
link_x2_x1(x) = c*sqrt((2+x)/(2*x))

set link x2 via link_x1_x2(x) inverse link_x2_x1(x)

# you want to set x2 tics at x1 = 100 and x1 = 1000
# check the corresponding x2 values 
print "x2 = x1( 100) = ", link_x1_x2(100)
print "x2 = x1(1000) = ", link_x1_x2(1000)

# set the tics with formatted tic labels as an example
set x2tics ("a: %.2e" link_x1_x2(100), "b: %.2e" link_x1_x2(1000))

set ylabel "Quantity y"
set ytics 0.2
set samples 400
Spectrum(x) = exp(-(x-500)**2/(400))


# this seems not to work with explicit tics
# set format x2 "%.2f"

plot Spectrum(x) w l title "Spectrum"
```

This is the output:

[image: x2 axis linked to x1 axis]

If you need logarithmic axes and the `set link` command does not work, you can replace it by setting the x2axis properties explicitly with `set x2range`. See the modified script:

```
set xlabel "Quantity lower"
set xtics nomirror
set x2label "Quantity Upper"
set x2tics nomirror


# setup the link functions
c = 1.548458 # or 2*1.548458 ?
link_x1_x2(x) = 2*c**2/(2*x**2-c**2) 
link_x2_x1(x) = c*sqrt((2+x)/(2*x))

xmin = 30
xmax = 2000
set xrange[xmin:xmax]
set x2range[link_x1_x2(xmin):link_x1_x2(xmax)]

set logscale x 
set logscale y 
set logscale x2

# set the tics at x1 = 100 and x1 = 1000
set x2tics ("a: %.2e" link_x1_x2(100), "b: %.2e" link_x1_x2(1000))

set ylabel "Quantity y"
#set ytics 0.2 # this must be improved for logarithmic plotting
set samples 400
Spectrum(x) = exp(-(x-500)**2/(400))

plot Spectrum(x) w l title "Spectrum"
```

This is the result:

[image: manual linkage]

Note that the drop of the function at about x1 = 1000 is caused by numerical underflow.

---

*Update:*

As we did not get the automatic linking to work for logarithmic plots, I would add minor tics manually. See `help set xtics` for details.

```
# just for a check
set grid mxtics
# set the tics at x1 = 100 and x1 = 1000
# set minor tics in between (at level 1)
set x2tics ("a: %.2e" link_x1_x2(100), \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(200) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(300) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(400) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(500) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(600) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(700) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(800) 1,      \ 
            "" link_x1_x2(900) 1,      \ 
            "b: %.2e" link_x1_x2(1000))
```

Now we have this result:

[image: add minor tics]

Comment: Hi, thanks! That works for me, the only issue I have is that when I format x and y to have log formatting `set logscale x` etc.. it doesn't work. Can this be fixed? I read somewhere that the log formatting is not compatible with linking axes.

Comment: @CAF I have added a workaround for logarithmic scales.

Comment: Hi, sorry to come back to this thread, but do you know if it's possible to put minor tic marks on the x2 axis? (I would  like 8 marks between the major tics). Thanks.

Comment: @CAF We did not get the automatic linking to work, right? So I would add them manually.

Comment: yup I just remembered, I’ve set it manually thanks but set mx2tics add ( ... ) didn’t work only set x2tics add (...). It’s not a big deal if the tics are minor or not but was just curious if I need to use a different syntax for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CAF I'm not sure from your comment and I don't know whether you got a notification: have you seen the update to the answer? `set x2tics` can take a "level" number which must be 1 for minor tics.